# iwlist and iw dev inconsistencies

Tags: linux, networking

I've come across a strange behavior while trying to scan the network. I have internal WiFI and external dongle plugged in. `iw dev wlan0 scan ap-force` returns `command failed: No such device (-19)`, while `iwlist scan wlan0` succeeds. Running iw dev yields following result:

```
phy#0
    Interface wlan1
            ifindex 4
            wdev 0x1
            addr dc:a6:32:32:dd:b4
            ssid 1000000097a21ff7
            type AP
            channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
            txpower 31.00 dBm
```

As you can see, there is only one interface listed while `ip link`'s output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:32:dd:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:37:45:4c:92:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:32:dd:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

lists both interfaces.

Wlan0 uses wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf to connect to the network and wlan1 is used by dnsmasq and hostapd to create a hotspot.

---

Is there something I am missing why iw dev shows only one interface?

How reliable is the configuration when both AP and client are using the same physical interface? - I know there are limitation in form of having the same channel at cetra.

Comment: iw will only work with new drivers that support nl80211. If you have old drivers for wlan0, use iwconfig.

Comment: @stark wlan0 is the rpi built-in wifi